# Is there a website where I can see new applications for linux/ubuntu?

Tags: websites

Is there a website where I can see New applications for linux/ubuntu? I want to find new applications that are available for linux , is there an easy way?

Answer (score 4):

You mean something like these?

http://www.getdeb.net/welcome/

http://packages.ubuntu.com/

Answer (score -1):

Try [Softpedia](http://linux.softpedia.com). I personally prefer it.